# Is there a way to see if Android Activity was started by Back Button

Tags: android, android-intent

Can I use any lifecycle method to check whether my activity was started by pressing the back button?

Comment: did you want **onRestart()**? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: you can see [This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) for understand better

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had some trouble because of Facebook which I was able to solve (I explained it in an answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly stated by shayan the onRestart method is triggered (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) if an activity gets "restarted", i.e. started again.

All member variables will have the same state as when you left the activity. So you can use any boolean flags for anything special.

In my case, the activity I want to check for "coming back via back button" is my StartActivity, where users can login via Facebook. The Facebook button starts Facebook's LoginActivity, which then returns to my StartActivity and triggers onRestart the first time. When I then leave my StartActivity I set a boolean flag to true before I start my MainActivity. When the user now presses the back button, the StartActivity.onRestart is triggered, and I can check my previously set boolean flag to check what I wanted to know.

Comment: but is not secure way, because might your activity destroyed for low memory or other thing.

Comment: Any suggestions how to do it better? :)

Comment: you can use Shared Preference to store value, or i think use Application object is better than this approach, but i recommend use SP.